# I Really Expect an Exception Here

Tags: android, sockets, exception

I'm developing an application for Android 4.03. The code of relevance is this:

```
public void startConnection() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Beginning");

                _socket = new Socket(_server, _port);
                _socket.setSoTimeout(DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

                _writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(_socket.getOutputStream()));
                _reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream()));

                _in = new InputThread(_reader, new InputThreadObserver());
                _in.start();

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "End");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "UnknownHostException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IOException");
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The creation of the socket is performed in a new thread, otherwise the execution freezes for few seconds.

If I set the variable `_server` to an existing host (for example `www.google.com`) everything goes all right. But if I set the `_server` variable to an host that does not exist (for example `asd.asd`) I really expect "UnknownHostException" to be printed in the logger. This does not happen (but the `_socket` variable is `null`). It just prints "Beginning" (and not "End"). Any Idea?

### EDIT:

The variables are declared like this:

```
private String _server;
private Socket _socket;
private int _port;
private BufferedWriter _writer;
private BufferedReader _reader;
private InputThread _in;
```

### EDIT:

I'm trying this:

```
public void startConnection() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Beginning");

                _socket = new Socket(_server, _port);

                if (_socket == null)
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NULL SOCKET! (test 1)");                        

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "EXCEPTION!");
            }

            if (_socket == null)
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NULL SOCKET! (test 2)");
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Don't know why but the output is only:

```
Beginning
```

### EDIT:

After 3 minutes and 13 seconds waiting i finally got:

```
EXCEPTION!
NULL SOCKET! (test 2)
```

Is that normal? Shouldn't the UnknownHostException be thrown immediatly?

Comment: As you don't have a 'catch-all' exception, i.e., `catch (Exception e)`, are you sure there isn't an unhandled exception being logged which you haven't spotted? If you're filtering logcat to only show messages for `LOG_TAG` tags there may be something you are missing when reading logcat.

Comment: Just added. No, there is no exception. I can't figure out why...

Comment: try moving this code out of a separate thread, and into your main execution, and see what you get

Comment: Are you saying you're getting a null socket, but you're not getting a Null Pointer Exception when you're setting the timeout?

Comment: No `NullPointerException` here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), if _server is a String, then you'll get an UnknownHost exception.  If it's any of the other possibilities, you won't.
In particular this signature will create the exception:

```
Socket(String host,
          int port)
   throws UnknownHostException,
          IOException
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but yes, `_server` is a `String`. And the exception is not thrown.

Comment: Are you getting the NPE then?  I just copied and pasted your code into a test project and got the expected UnknownHostException.  Could it be your Java or Android version?

Comment: I'm developing a Android 4.0.3 API level 15 project. And I'm testing it in my HTC Desire Z Android 2.3.3.